# (OpenCart) View Images Uploaded by Customer

Tags: php, image, upload, resize, opencart

I am trying to upload an image from customer product page (upload file option), the image is uploaded to `system/upload` folder and renamed with: filename + md5 hash string. So, for example I upload `image.jpg`, the file will be uploaded to `system/upload/image.jpg.392da1267fbfa4be65f7859bb0b974d9`.

Now I want to see that image uploaded by customer from admin page (I created a new module page), how can I resize and display the image file? I can get the file name from table `oc_upload` in database, but the phisical file is using modified name which has no extension, I cannot resize this file because it is located in `system/upload` folder and its extension is changed. The image resize tool can only resize images in `image` folder with some allowed extensions configured in Settings page.

Any idea how to display images uploaded by customer? Do I need to copy the renamed uploaded file to `image` folder using its original name and then resize and display it? I appreciate any of your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to resize the file itself. You could just use CSS properties width and height on an <img> tag, couldn't you ?

Comment: Resize to generate the thumbnails of the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the solution by copying the `resize()` method in `admin/model/tool/image.php` to my controller and modify it to resize image from `system/upload` folder.

```
    private function resizeImageUpload($old_filename, $width, $height, $new_filename = '') {

            $extension_arr = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');

            $old_image = $old_filename;

            if (!empty($new_filename)) {
                $extension = pathinfo($new_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $new_image = 'cache/system/upload/' . utf8_substr($new_filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($new_filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;
            } else {
                $extension = pathinfo($old_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $new_image = 'cache/system/upload/' . utf8_substr($old_filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($old_filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;
            }

            if (!in_array($extension, $extension_arr)) return '';

            if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image) || (filectime(DIR_UPLOAD . $old_image) > filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image))) {
                $path = '';

                $directories = explode('/', dirname(str_replace('../', '', $new_image)));

                foreach ($directories as $directory) {
                        $path = $path . '/' . $directory;

                        if (!is_dir(DIR_IMAGE . $path)) {
                                @mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . $path, 0777);
                        }
                }

                list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize(DIR_UPLOAD . $old_image);

                if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
                        $image = new Image(DIR_UPLOAD . $old_image);
                        $image->resize($width, $height);
                        $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
                } else {
                        $success = copy(DIR_UPLOAD . $old_image, DIR_IMAGE . $new_image);
                }
            }

        if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
            return HTTPS_CATALOG . 'image/' . $new_image;
        } else {
            return HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/' . $new_image;
        }
    }
```